# Find maximum weight simple cycle in random complete oriented graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am looking for an efficient (i.e. polynomial or superpolynomial but subexponential) algorithm to find the simple cycle(s) of maximum weight in a very specific class of complete oriented weighted graphs $G = (V, E, w)$ where $w$ is random and *quasi* anti-symetrical:
\begin{cases}
\forall v_i \in V & w_{ii} = 0\\
\forall (v_i \neq v_j) \in V^2 & w_{ij} \approx -w_{ji}\\
\end{cases}

Where $w_{ij} \approx -w_{ji}$ means: $w_{ij} + w_{ji} = \epsilon_{ij}$ with $\epsilon_{ij}$ random and $|\epsilon_{ij}| << |w_{ij}|$.

Such graphs are found in flow analysis with hysteresis, or in arbitrage analysis in finance.

I know that in general, finding a cycle of maximum weigth is NP-hard. However the case above comes with very strong restrictions (random quasi antisymetry) so there might be tricks to speed up the search, be it probabilistic or not.

N.B. I have played with Bellman's and Floyd's algorithms. However, because of the presence of negative and positive cycles, I couldn't have them do what I want.

Comment: Could you provide some information about the distribution of the weights?

Comment: We can assume the weights follow a log-normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 10$.